# Ubuntu server 14.04.1 network drop packets e1000e

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new with linux OS.

We have currently a Ubuntu Server **14.04.1 LTS** x64 installed, and it has some network performance problems.

This is my ifconfig output

```
p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:76:a7:b8
          inet addr:192.168.15.250  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe76:a7b8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:54129879 errors:0 dropped:2805 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57851574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:51180098811 (51.1 GB)  TX bytes:39929336217 (39.9 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7900000-f7920000
```

Note, that's dropping packets...

There is no system load problems (CPU and Memory).

This is the `ethtool -i` output:

```
driver: e1000e
version: 3.1.0.2-NAPI
firmware-version: 2.1-2
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

After some research I found a bug-report about my card at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1018561

I tried this too:

http://www.doxer.org/resolved-intel-e1000e-driver-bug-on-82574l-ethernet-controller-causing-network-blipping/

How can I fix the dropping?

Comment: Can you describe a little, what your peformance issues are? How looks the load of the system? Does it also happen with other hardware at this ethernetport?

Comment: @frlan "Does it also happen with other hardware at this ethernetport" this I didn't test

Comment: The first thing to do is to update to a supported release.